# Como poner resultado en un input desde javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Una ayuda, como haría para que el resultado me lo pusiera en un input, para poder guardar el resultado en un base de datos ?
Para quitar el div, ayuda por favor

```js
function calcularEdad()
  {
   var fecha=document.getElementById("user_date").value;
   if(validate_fecha(fecha)==true)
   {
    var values=fecha.split("-");
    var dia = values[2];
    var mes = values[1];
    var ano = values[0];

    var fecha_hoy = new Date();
    var ahora_ano = fecha_hoy.getYear();
    var ahora_mes = fecha_hoy.getMonth()+1;
    var ahora_dia = fecha_hoy.getDate();

    var edad = (ahora_ano + 1900) - ano;
    if ( ahora_mes < mes )
    {
     edad--;
    }
    if ((mes == ahora_mes) && (ahora_dia < dia))
    {
     edad--;
    }
    if (edad > 1900)
    {
     edad -= 1900;
    }

    var meses=0;
    if (ahora_mes>mes)
     meses=ahora_mes-mes;
    if (ahora_mes<mes)
     meses=12-(mes-ahora_mes);
    if (ahora_mes==mes && dia>ahora_dia)
     meses=11;

    var dias=0;
    if (ahora_dia>dia)
     dias=ahora_dia-dia;
    if (ahora_dia<dia)
    {
     ultimoDiaMes=new Date(ahora_ano, ahora_mes, 0);
     dias=ultimoDiaMes.getDate()-(dia-ahora_dia);
    }

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Tienes "+edad+" años";
   }
   else
   {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="La fecha "+fecha+" es incorrecta";
   }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pasar un valor a un input, en vez de hacer esto

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Tienes "+edad+" años";
```

Ssititúyelo por lo siguiente

```
document.getElementById("result").value ="Tienes "+edad+" años";
```

Haciendo uso de `value` puedes asignar de forma dinámica el valor generado al contenido de un `input`